# validate a nested json using Ecto.changeset schemaless

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've started to write an application with Elixir and Phoenix, but I am a little bit lost.

Basically the application will receive a complex JSON and I need to validate it and save it in the database.

Something like this:

My json:

```
{
    "id": 42,
    "name": "Alan",
    "address": {
        "universe": "C-137"
    }
}
```

My table

```
| id | person_id | data                     |
| #  | 42        | {"id": 42,"name": "Al... |
```

The problem is that I don't know how to validate the JSON.

Probably **changeset** is what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to use it to validate a JSON with nested objects.

I would like to make something like this:

```
defmodule Foo.Person do
  import Ecto.Changeset

  def types("person") do
    %{id: :integer, name: :string, address: types("address")}
  end

  def types("address") do
    %{universe: :string}
  end

  def changeset(data) do
    {data, types("person")}
    |> cast(data, Map.keys(types("person")))
    # |> other validation rules ...
  end
end
```

I only achieve this objective using a **Schema** but I don't want to save each part of JSON separately in my database.

Someone know if there is some trick to do it?

Comment: use erlang driver for mongodb?

Comment: Hi Jiang YD, thank you. I'm almost getting it with the **embeds_one**. If it doesn't work I'll check the Erlang mong driver. And ill post here when it works